# Postfix conditional rules base on sending address

Tags: postfix, rules, conditional

Email configuration on dev server: At the moment I have postfix configured to route all emails sent to itself. So if you try to send and email to any address say gareth@example.com it won't be delivered the that address, instead you would check the email locally at archive@hostname.com.

This is the expected behaviour as we don't accidentally want to email thousands of users on our dev server.

We want to use git post-receive-email to notify the testers that a new commit have been deployed and is ready for testing. I have already set this part up but obviously is re-routed by postfix as explained above.

How can I create a type of whitelist email that will not conform to the rule above. Say if the to address is gareth@example.com then it's sent to gareth@example.com but if the email to address is anything else then it's routed to archive@hostname.com

The only special config I have is /etc/posfix/main.cnf and it contains

```
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
myhostname = hostname.com
mydomain = hostname.com
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain, $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks_style = host
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/28, 10.92.40.39/24
relay_domains = $mydestination
relayhost = 127.0.0.1
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1, localhost
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
mailbox_size_limit = 0
always_bcc = archive@localhost
```

Comment: You can use postfix alias maps and regexp , for example
alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/aliases
/^gareth@example.com$/     gareth@example.com
/^*@example.com$/    archive@hostname.com

Comment: How do you reroute your mails?

Comment: I have just updated question with more information

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be [`sender_dependent_default_transport_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_default_transport_maps) or [`sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_relayhost_maps). With more information about your configuration you would probably get more detailed help here.

Comment: I have just updated question with more information is that what you are after?